# Is iOS device UDID available in crash report?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In an iOS crash report is the UDID of the device that had the crash listed anywhere?  From what I can see it isn't but curious if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I just checked mine and I don't see it, just the CrashReporter Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't appear in crash reports. The only thing remotely close to identifying the device that I can see is the hardware model and the iOS build.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no it isn't.